# How to add row corresponding to Date and other weather variables?

Tags: r, date, tidyverse

The sample dataset is as below:

| Date | Gender | temp | number of admission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/11/2023 | F | 10 degree celsius | 12 |
| 17/11/2023 | M | 12 degree celsius | 20 |
| 17/11/2023 | F | 12 degree celsius | 12 |

My expected outcome is:

| Date | Gender | temp | number of admission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/11/2023 | M | 10 degree celsius | 0 |
| 16/11/2023 | F | 10 degree celsius | 12 |
| 17/11/2023 | M | 12 degree celsius | 20 |
| 17/11/2023 | F | 12 degree celsius | 12 |

Is there anyway to add rows without filling the weather variable(i.e. temp) by hand?